# MySQL session won't start on XAMPP - Buffer pool(s) not load

Tags: mysql, xampp

My MySQL won't start and it shows like this:

```
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:55:53 ق.ظ  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

and then this is the error logs:

```
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.22 started; log sequence number 1463371418; transaction id 661011
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-29 10:55:51 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

and error in Windows Event Viewer:

Log Name:      Application
Source:        MariaDB
Date:          07/07/1401 11:32:33 ق.ظ
Event ID:      100
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DESKTOP-33KUAJ5
Description:
The description for Event ID 100 from source MariaDB cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

Aborting

The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table

Event Xml:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="MariaDB" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">100</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-09-29T08:02:33.6734979Z" />
    <EventRecordID>20403</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="0" ThreadID="0" />
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>DESKTOP-33KUAJ5</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Aborting

</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

What is the cause of these errors and how can I fix it?

Comment: Most often this is because you already have another DBMS, possibly MySQL already installed. Remember XAMPP has an old version of mariaDB installed. Both these DBMS's by default try and use port 3306. Do you have another MySQL/mariaDB already installed

Comment: I have not installed any DBSM. It was working until 4 days ago. But today it suddenly stopped working.

Comment: I dont suppose you installed MySQL Workbench by any chance?

Comment: You could also check the Windows Event Viewer for messages from mariaDB, maybe there is a log of whats causing the issue

Comment: Yes. There are several error messages from MariaDB in Windows Event Viewer

Comment: Ok, so if you share those with us we can see what they say and maybe help you work out whats wrong, add then to the question using the Edit link under the question box

Answer (score 1):

This is how it was fixed for me :

Open shell and start MySQL with this command:

```
mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking
```

Repair database with this command:

```
mysqlcheck -r --databases mysql --use-frm
```

Stop MySQL, restart MySQL from XAMP.

Source : [MySQL Forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,652134,652135#msg-652135)

Comment: It didn't work.
`mysqlcheck: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) when trying to connect`

Comment: Check if SQLservice is actually running: 
1)'Windowskey + R' and type ' services.msc'  
2)if you find the service there called "MySQL" start it if it is stopped. 

If you dont find it :
1)Open a cmd (as admin)
2) cd to mysql install directory bin
3) run the command C:\...\bin>mysqld.exe -- install
4)check back again in services and start it.
Then follow the original answer again . Hope it helps!